# ¿Como insertar valores cada cierto numero de elementos de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente array:

**`datos = ['Rita', 'Pedro', 'Miguel', 'Ana', 'Juan', 'Rosa'];`**

Y el siguiente código de `Google Apps Script`:

```
function enviarInfo(datos){

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
     var ws = ss.getSheetByName("PRUEBA");

     ws.appendRow(datos);
}
```

Al insertar el `array` obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Inserción de array completa]

Sin embargo, estoy buscando **insertar una fila por cada 3 elementos**, como esto:

[image: Inserción que deseo obtener]

¿Es posible hacer esto y como?

Comment: Es necesario que el codigo sea en google app script. O te serviria un codigo normal de javascript.

Comment: un codigo normal de javascript me ayudaria a darme una idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una posible solución, sobre todo si la cantidad total no es múltiplo de 3:

```
function enviarInfo() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("PRUEBA");

  var datos = ['Rita', 'Pedro', 'Miguel', 'Ana', 'Juan', 'Rosa', 'Pepe', 'Juan2'];

  var res = [[]];
  var g = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && !(i % 3)) {
      res[++g] = [];
    }
    res[g].push(datos[i])
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < res.length; k++) {
    ws.appendRow(res[k]);
  }    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si es posible y hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Va un ejemplo:

```js
var datos = ['Rita', 'Pedro', 'Miguel', 'Ana', 'Juan', 'Rosa'];
var salida = [];
for(var i = 0; i < datos.length / 3; i++){
  var j = i * 3;
  salida.push( datos.slice(j, j + 3));
}
console.info(salida);
```

La solución anterior usa un bucle `for`, los métodos `Array.prototype.slice`, `Array.prototype.length`, `Array.prototype.push` y los operadores `<`, `/`, `++`, `*` y `+`

- `<`, `/` se usan para determinar el número de iteraciones que en este caso es el número de miembros del Array `datos` entre 3 que es el número de "columnas" que debe tener la variable `salida`.
- `++` para incrementar una unidad al iterador.
- `push` para insertar una "fila" al Array `salida`.
- `slice` para obtener una "fila".
- `*` y `+` para obtener los índices de inicio y fin de las "filas".

Para implementarlo en Google Apps Script simplemente pon el código dentro del bloque de la declaración de una función, la impresión de la consola lo puedes ver en la página de ejecuciones de tu proyecto en https://script.google.com.

NOTA: Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript pero no soporta todas las características incorporadas en ECMAScript 5, entre ellas `TypedArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar esto tienes que hacer un bucle:

¿Cuántas veces tienes que iterar en el bucle? La función ws.appendRow te deja añadir una fila. Como tienes que crear filas de tres elementos, tendrás que llamar a esa función numero_elementos / 3 veces. Por ejemplo para 6 elementos: 6/3 -> 2 veces. Ahí tienes el número de veces que tienes que iterar en el bucle.

¿Qué hago en cada iteración del bucle? Tendrás que generar un array nuevo para pasarle a appendRow. El nuevo array tendrá 3 elementos. En la primera iteración serán el 0, 1 y 2, en la segunda 3, 4, 5, etc. Es edecir que lo que va dentro del array es [3*i + 0, 3*i+1, 3*i+2] donde i es el número de iteración en el que estás. Para hacer esto puedes hacerlo manualmente o te puedes ayudar de alguna función como subarray: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/TypedArray/subarray

Tendrás que considerar también que pasa si cuentas con 5 elementos. ¿Qué pasa con la última fila? Mandas un array de menos elementos, o mandas un array con 3 elementos pero con espacios en blancos / null?

Dale un intento, y si no te sale pega el código que hayas elaborado y lo dejamos fino

Comment: los datos vienen de 6 inputs con valores requeridos, es por eso que no pueden existir solo 5 datos o valores null o vacios, intentare hacer un bucle como lo comentas

Comment: El código en la pregunta usa Google Apps Script, que aunque está basado en JavaScript, no soporta todas las "noveadades" de ECMAScript 5. ¿Has usado subarrays en Google Apps Script?